# Why does the script package in atom not work with command but does manually?

Tags: python, python-3.x, atom-editor

I am using Windows 10, and Python 3.6 (installed at C:\Users\George\Anaconda3\python.exe).  I have also installed Atom and am trying to use it as a python development environment with the script package.

An issue I consistently come across with is running my code using script.  Checked other answers here but to no avail.
As an example, this is some code in a atom-test.py file:

```
import numpy as np
myArray = np.array([1,2,3,4])
print(np.sum(myArray))
```

When I run it using ctrl+b (I changed ctrl+shift+b to ctrl+b), I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\George\atomtest1.py", line 1, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

However, the module is imported because I can easily do this with terminal and it works fine.
Then I realized that manually running the script from profile by going to Package>Script>Run with profile then selecting the profile where python is set in the command (in my case Users/George/Anaconda3/python.exe) then it works fine.

```
10
[Finished in 0.793s]
```

So what can I do to get it to run there just by selecting ctrl+b?

Comment: Try: `pip3 install numpy` and `pip install numpy` in terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem many times. A workaround that works for me is to just keep trying to run the script and restart Atom. After a while, it kicks in and runs and all is fine. I know this answer sucks but it works for me. I just now ran into this problem. It started working on 3rd restart and continued for a while.